# React: converting whole numbers to numbers with dot separators

Tags: reactjs

I have to put a number in state (1400000) and then do mathematical operations with it. Problem is, I need the format of the number to be displayed as: "1.400.000". I thought about a Regex, but I have no idea how to implement it. Any ideas?

```
   class MyComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super()
        this.contentEditable = React.createRef();
        this.state = {html: "1400000", size: 380};
      };

      handleChange = evt => {
        this.setState({html: evt.target.value});
      };

      render = () => {
        return 
<div><ContentEditable
                  innerRef={this.contentEditable}
                  html={this.state.html} 
                  disabled={false}       
                  onChange={this.handleChange} 
                />
<p>{this.state.price/this.state.size}</p>
      };
    };
```

Comment: [Tried this but with a `.` instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: Did. Doesn´t really seem to work: function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
    return parts.join(".");
}, numberWithCommas(1.440.000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i can propose you ready solution with npm package [react-number-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format)

You can represent number in format which you want, just set needed attributes, for example for you:
instead `<p>{this.state.price/this.state.size}</p>`
you can use:

```
<NumberFormat value={this.state.price/this.state.size} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={'.'}  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to format your text. This way you wouldn't have to include any (possibly) uneccesary components.

```
Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {}).format(14000000).replace(/,/g,'.');
```

Hope this helps,